# What is the exact criteria for unlocking Aleister Crowley?

Tags: the-curious-expedition

In "The Curious Expedition", it gives the criteria to unlock Aleister Crowley as:

> Finish every expedition in a game (rank 3+) with good standing.

I'm a little confused as to what this means. I understand that I have to *finish* each expedition (so I can't escape via hot air balloon, scroll, etc.) I understand that my *rank* among the other explorers must be *3 or more*. But I'm confused about the "every expedition with good standing" portion of the wording.

1. At the end of **EACH** expedition, I must have a good standing with the locals?
2. At the end of the **LAST** expedition, I must have a good standing with the locals?

Option 1 seems to be very difficult to reach, as there are not many chances to increase your standing in the first and second expeditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having finally unlocked Aleister Crowley last night, I can verify that unlocking him requires a good standing at the end of EACH expedition, not just the end of the last expedition. In my case, my standing at the end of each expedition was at least 3.

This is pretty difficult to do. I did it by avoiding taking treasure from shrines, as well as trading with the locals as much as possible. I also avoiding killing any animals, and I used the stone circles sparingly.